# Multiple slicing and converting a huge txt file into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, etl

I'm trying to work on a huge txt file containing 169566 lines/rows, each one is exactly like this:

> "aaaabbcccccccddfffffffffggghhhhhhhiijkkkkkkkkkkk"

Each line has a pre-defined range for each field, such as *names* (76 alfa) and *birthdays*(8 int/num).
I'd love to know if there is a way to slice it using pandas, as *column 1* as *"a"*, from `[:4]`, *column 2* as *"b"*, from `[5:8]` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

you want to use [pd.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) for this. it enables you to read fixed-width files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, acushner! It helped a lot.
I used this to slice the columns:

```
widths = [
    9, #name
    19, #title
    6, #salary
]
df = pd.read_fwf("fixed_width.txt", widths=widths)
df
```

found this example [here](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations-2017/pandas/opening-fixed-width-files/)

Answer (score 0):

I used this little trick with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd   
a = list ('aaaabbcccccccddfffffffffggghhhhhhhiijkkkkkkkkkkk')
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':a})
grouped_df= df.groupby('col')['col'].count()
print (grouped_df)
```

[image]

you can give any name to the column that you are crating using groupby.